# Issue using values from layout that starts with setVisibility(View.GONE);

Tags: java, android, view

I have an app that connects to a serial device. When I start my application I want settings to be hidden, so I have the linearlayout set to invisible and gone. However this means the connection isn't established. There is some problem that if the view is set to gone, then the default values that I've set in the spinners cant be read, why is this and how do I fix it.

If the settings are hidden and I connect, once I open the settings the connection works fine.

So it works fine if both layouts are shown like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgntQ.png

It works fine if the settings layout is invisible:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs3yq.png

But if its gone it doesnt work until I bring out the settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoYtM.png

Here is an example of a spinner I make in onCreate with default 9600

```
mBaudSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bannerBaudSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mBaudSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        String[] tempArray = SlickUSB2Serial.BAUD_RATES;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            adapter.add(tempArray[i]);
        }
        mBaudSpinner.setSelection(SlickUSB2Serial.BaudRate.BAUD_9600.ordinal());
```

Edit:

Here is some code that happens when a conenction is found, but isn't getting called when view is gone, I've implemented library methods here:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //bannerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //bannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG3, "in onItemSelected");
        changeSelectedAdapter(mDeviceAdapters.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void changeSelectedAdapter(USB2SerialAdapter adapter) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "in changeselectedadapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        // if(mSelectedAdapter!=null){
        // mDeviceOutputs.set(mDeviceSpinnerAdapter.getPosition(mSelectedAdapter.getDeviceId()+""),mReceiveBox.getText().toString());
        Log.d(TAG3, "in change selected adapter");
        mSelectedAdapter = adapter;
        mBaudSpinner.setSelection(adapter.getBaudRate().ordinal());
        mDataSpinner.setSelection(adapter.getDataBit().ordinal());
        mParitySpinner.setSelection(adapter.getParityOption().ordinal());
        mStopSpinner.setSelection(adapter.getStopBit().ordinal());

        updateCurrentSettingsText();

        // mReceiveBox.setText(mDeviceOutputs.get(mDeviceSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()));
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Adapter switched toooo: " + adapter.getDeviceId() + "!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String getInitialPrompt = "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\n";
        try {
            sendOverSerial(getInitialPrompt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "exception");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdapterConnected(USB2SerialAdapter adapter) {
        adapter.setDataListener(this);
        mDeviceAdapters.add(adapter);
        mDeviceOutputs.add("");
        mDeviceSpinnerAdapter.add("" + adapter.getDeviceId());
        mDeviceSpinner.setSelection(mDeviceSpinnerAdapter.getCount() - 1);

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Adapter: " + adapter.getDeviceId() + " Connected!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

This does get called:

```
public void onAdapterConnected(USB2SerialAdapter adapter) {
        adapter.setDataListener(this);
        mDeviceAdapters.add(adapter);
        mDeviceOutputs.add("");
        mDeviceSpinnerAdapter.add("" + adapter.getDeviceId());
        mDeviceSpinner.setSelection(mDeviceSpinnerAdapter.getCount() - 1);

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Adapter: " + adapter.getDeviceId() + " Connected!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

I need this to be called but it is not:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //bannerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //bannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG3, "in onItemSelected");
        changeSelectedAdapter(mDeviceAdapters.get(position));
    }
```

The only reference I have to onItemListener is in onCreate, so is it not being processed because the spinner is "gone"?

```
mDeviceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bannerDeviceSpinner);
        mDeviceSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        mDeviceSpinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mDeviceSpinner.setAdapter(mDeviceSpinnerAdapter);
        mDeviceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

here is the documentation for mSelectedadapter, i.imgur.com/Ezigt7G.png

it is defined like this in my app:

```
private static USB2SerialAdapter mSelectedAdapter;
```

Comment: If you know the selection when the app starts why do you need to get the selection from the spinner instead of just using the selected value?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set the initial values is the problem here, quite new to this. If I trymSelectedAdapter.setCommSettings(BaudRate.BAUD_9600, DataBits.DATA_8_BIT, ParityOption.PARITY_NONE, StopBits.STOP_1_BIT); the app crashes

Comment: It crashes because mSelectedAdapter is null, becuase changeSelectedAdapter doesn't get called  unless I bring out the settings. It's called if the settings are visible, but I don;t know why

Comment: do you need to call `mSelectedAdapter` when the view is `gone`? if no you maybe will not need to call it, or initialize mSelectedAdapter with some default values, when your view is in `gone` state

Comment: here is the documentation for mSelectedadapter, http://i.imgur.com/Ezigt7G.png Not sure how to set default vals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that although the adapter was getting connected, changeSelectedAdapter was not getting called, as onItemSelected was not being called. This was because an item must not be selected if the view is set to gone?

Two ways to fix this:

Manually call it when the connection is established:

```
changeSelectedAdapter(mSelectedAdapter);
```

Or when the adapter connects I can set up some default vals:

```
mSelectedAdapter = adapter;
mSelectedAdapter.setCommSettings(BaudRate.BAUD_9600, DataBits.DATA_8_BIT, ParityOption.PARITY_NONE, StopBits.STOP_1_BIT);
```

A third way is to have the view visible, but set the size to some tiny size programatically, then you can change it back to the desired size as necessary